# Open a Oracle 7.3.x database in Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Is there any way to open or convert an old Oracle 7.x database into Oracle 11g?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to upgrade in stages, which wouldn't actually be possible now because Oracle 8.x and 9.x are now unsupported and the software is unavailable (unless you have an Oracle support contract and ask them for copies of the software). Read the [Oracle® Database Upgrade Guide
11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/toc.htm) for more information.

Your best bet, assuming you have the 7.x database up and running, is to use `exp` to export the schemas you require, then import them into a fresh 11.2.x database.